# How to Print out a particular way using nested loops with print writer

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, printwriter

I am trying to read a file and print out information a certain way

This is my current method

```
public class PrintImpl {

public void createReport(PropertyLogImpl propertyLogImpl, RealtorLogImpl realtorLogImpl, String fileName) {
    System.out.println("Creating clean report..");
    System.out.println("Report is complete -- located in file: " + fileName);

    try {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        LinkedList<Property> propertyList = propertyLogImpl.getPropertyList();
        System.out.println("Realtor Log:");
        RealtorNode listTop = realtorLogImpl.getListTop();
        RealtorNode temp = listTop;
        Iterator<Property> iter = propertyList.iterator();
        propertyLogImpl.setPropertyList(propertyList);
        Property property = iter.next();

        while (temp != null) {
            writer.println(temp.getRealtor().getLicenseNumber() + " " + temp.getRealtor().getLastName() + ", " + temp.getRealtor().getFirstName());

            if (temp.getRealtor().getLicenseNumber().compareTo(property.getLicenseNumber()) == 0) {
                writer.println("    " + property.getMlsNumber() + " "
                        + property.getStreetAdress() + " "
                        + property.getBedrooms()
                        + "/" + property.getBathrooms() + "$ "
                        + property.getAskingPrice() + " "
                        + property.isSold());

                writer.println("        " + property.getCity() + ", "
                        + property.getState() + ", " + property.getZipCode());
                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    property = iter.next();
                }
            }

        }
        temp = temp.getNextNode();

        writer.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        System.out.println("File was not found");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

But the thing is, it gets stuck in an infinite loop. So what its suppose to do is match a realtor license number with a property license number. The property is a linked list and the realtor is a Node thats like a linked list. Basically what im trying to do is get one node, and itterate through the properties and print out all the properties under that on realtor. Then switch to the next node and repeat. But none of the loops i tried have worked. Please help!

This is what the file is suppose to look like

```
CD4524521 snart, paul
         1254294         246 wart street       2/3.0   $   456321.00    SOLD
                     somewhere, CO 54236

          1683946       879  Main St            2/2.0   $   646589.00   
               Somehwere, CO 45726
```

It would look like that, just the realtor name and then keep adding properties to the realtor, after there is no more properties for the realtor, switch to a new realtor and keep adding properties for that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`temp = temp.getNextNode();` is outside of the while-loop. So the value of `temp` is never changed. This is why you get an infinite loop, as your while-condition is `temp != null`.

Also, i'd recommend you to think about overriding the `toString()` method of that `Property` class or add another method to get a nicely formatted string representation of the properties. Your code looks very cluttered if you start puzzling those strings together for the output in the while loop.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return prop1 + "\t" + prop2
        + "whatever" + somefield;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apart from the temp variable beeing outside of the loop (as noted by @mumpitz), you could also use

```
writer.printf("%s %d    ...","string",1234)
```

so that you have the formatting separated from the fields.
Also StringBuilder makes this a bit more comfortable.

If you have more complex stuff to be formatted in the near future, have a look at MessageFormat: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html